# Setting Range Object from a specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel

How would you set the value of a Range Object to a specific range from a specific sheet?

I have code right now that navigates and activates the correct sheet and cell, but when I set the value of the range, and copy, it ends up copying a range from Sheet 1 when I want it to take a value from another sheet.

Here is the code I have right now when trying to set the Range.

```
    Dim NewValuesRange As Range
    Dim ActiveCellRowNumber As Integer
    Sheets(err).Activate
    Set NewValuesRange = Range(Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))
    NewValuesRange.Copy
    NewValuesRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

I've tried setting line four as:

```
    Set NewValuesRange = Sheets(err).Range(Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))
```

and

```
    Set NewValuesRange = Worksheet(sheetname).Range(Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))
```

However, those two give me an 1004 error. Any idea's on how to tackle this?

Thanks!

EDIT: err is an integer already set, activecellrownumber is an integer already set, and sheetname is a string that has been set.

Comment: Is `err` or `sheetname` a variable that has been defined?  Or are those the actual names of the spreadsheets?  If they are the names of the spreadsheets, try putting them in quotations (e.g.) `Worksheet("sheetname").Range...`

Comment: err is an integer that has the sheet number. sheetname is a string variable that i got from using ActiveSheet.name

Comment: How is `ActiveCellRowNumber` being set?  If you place a breakpoint on the line that you get the error, does it have a value?

Comment: yep it has a value. Its getting the correct row number on the sheet that I want to insert the range into.

Comment: Do a debug.print on all the variables (err, ActiveCellRowNumber, etc).  Since you're using ActiveCell references, you might want to check if you're switching between workbooks and such

Comment: I just stepped through the code, and it is activating the correct cell and correct worksheet. I also tried removing the variables and just putting numbers but for some reason it keeps throwing a 1004 error whenever I try to specifiy a specific sheet :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify both the Range and Cells calls with a Worksheet object:

```
Dim NewValuesRange As Range
Dim ActiveCellRowNumber As Integer
With Sheets(err)
Set NewValuesRange = .Range(.Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), .Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))
End With
NewValuesRange.Copy
NewValuesRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Note the use of both `.Range` and `.Cells` rather than just `Range` and `Cells`. I would assume your code is in a worksheet code module, in which case any reference to `Range` or `Cells` that doesn't specify a sheet explicitly refers to the sheet containing the code, not the active sheet. (i.e. it defaults to `Me.Range` rather than `Application.Range` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You must put some value in *ActiveCellRowNumber*

```
Sub fhskadjfhs()
    Dim NewValuesRange As Range
    Dim ActiveCellRowNumber As Integer
    Dim Errr As String

    Errr = "Sheet2"
    Sheets(Errr).Activate
    ActiveCellRowNumber = ActiveCell.Row
    Set NewValuesRange = Range(Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))
    NewValuesRange.Copy
    NewValuesRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that line when i made the post. ActiveCellRowNumber does have a value and its getting the correct one from the page I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub CopyAndInsert()

Dim NewValuesRange As Range
Dim ActiveCellRowNumber As Integer

    With Worksheets(err)
        Set NewValuesRange = .Range(Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 1), Cells(ActiveCellRowNumber - 1, 18))

        NewValuesRange.Copy
        NewValuesRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
End Sub
```